# Remove <br> tags when RemoveFormat is executed

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-5

I'm trying to extend `RemoveFormat` command to make it remove `<br>` tags.

I've tried altering `removefromat` format:

```js
            formats: {
                removeformat: [
                    {
                        selector: 'br',
                        remove: 'all'
                    }
                ]
            }
```

The code above for some reason **removes** `&nbsp;` from blank lines `<p>&nbsp;</p>`, this is not acceptable.

My second try was adding plugin and using `editor.selection.getContent`/`editor.selection.setContent`, but I can not find information how to **restore selection** with this approach.

Comment: Do you have something like this `valid_elements : '*[*]'` configured with your tinymce editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I configure my TinyMCE Editor like this it works for me:

```
  valid_elements : '*[*]',
  remove_trailing_brs: false,
  formats: {
    removeformat: [
      { selector: 'br', remove: 'all' }
    ]
  }
```

Here is a codepen example for this: https://codepen.io/jonas_weinhardt/pen/oNwmpaz

Maybe its helps you with your problem.

Comment: I tried your sample and it worked, then I did the same in my app and suddenly it worked. Maybe this was related to Angular update (we are using wrapper component).